# Puppet not recognising packages (which exist in yum) in Centos

Tags: puppet

I am trying to install a package in Centos using puppet.

The package can be installed using yum install (sudo yum install bash-completion), but puppet says it doen't exist! (I have had this problem when trying to install several other packages too).

Here is what I am using:

```
    file { '/etc/bash_completion.d/symfony2-autocomplete.bash':
        ensure => present,
        owner => 'vagrant',
        group => 'vagrant',
        mode => '0777',
        require => Package['bash-completion'],
        content => template('extras/symfony2-autocomplete.bash'),
    }
```

Is there a list of puppet packages available? (or maybe have I forgotten to include something somewhere?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not instructed Puppet to install a package at all.

```
file { '...': require => Package['...'] }
```

will not result in package installation. It just builds a relationship between a `file` resource and the named `package`.

```
package { 'bash-completion': ensure => 'installed' }
```

will do what you need. The `require` metaparameter will then work as well.

Comment: that worked thanks. After lots of trial and error, I realised that I needed to put the whole package name (xorg-x11-server-Xvfb instead of Xvfb, even though sudo yum install Xvfb works) using yum info -v was also quite helpful for anyone else reading!

Comment: Yes, the `package` resource will not behave just like `yum` in all contexts. For example, resources that can be provided by more than one package (which I suspect is the case for `Xvfb`) cannot be managed through Puppet so easily. You should indeed use the exact name of the package(s) in question.

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS 6, bash-completion is in the EPEL repository. You either forgot to [add EPEL](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/stahnma/epel), or your manifest is trying to install bash-completion before adding the EPEL repo.

It's in the base repositories in CentOS 7.

Oh, and your file ownership and permissions are wrong, but you probably knew that already...

Comment: Ah ha makes sense! Thanks!
And yes, I thought someone might pick up on that, thanks :P